# Begin and end tag on own line - vue html prettier

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prettier

I am using prettier in my Vue project to format my code. I've got some things I would like to change but I just can't find a solution for it on stackoverflow or anywhere else (github, google etc). I was hoping someone over here can help me out with this.

Giving this input

```
<router-link class="underline pointer" :to="routeToEditLocation(location.id)">{{ t('Edit') }}</router-link>
```

Gives me this output

```
<router-link
    class="underline pointer"
    :to="routeToEditLocation(location.id)"
>{{ t('Edit') }}</router-link>
```

But what I would like to see is this

```
<router-link
    class="underline pointer"
    :to="routeToEditLocation(location.id)"
>
    {{ t('Edit') }}
</router-link>
```

Anyone with a solution for my prettier settings? Using the following settings

```
trailingComma: "all"
tabWidth: 4
semi: true
singleQuote: true
arrowParens: "avoid"
prose-wrap: "never"
parser: "vue"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use `html-whitespace-sensitivity` and set it too `ignore`.

You could also add this comment before `router-link` to fix it.

```
<!-- display: block -->
```

Prettier cannot make this decision on its own as adding white spaces is not without consequences.

More details about whitespace sensitivity in prettier [here](https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting).